# How to implement Custom View as part of MVC?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, view

So I'm experimenting with implementing an MVC pattern in Android where my views are subclassed from RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, ScrollView, etc... It's working until I try to get a hold of a view within my view. I get an NPE. I've tried accessing the view in order to set the onClickListener in the constructor and also in onAttachedToWindow(), but I get the NPE in both places.

For example, here's a view class:

```
public class ViewAchievements extends LinearLayout
{
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayoutAchievement1;

    public ViewAchievements(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        mRelativeLayoutAchievement1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_achievement1);
        mRelativeLayoutAchievement1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) context); //NPE on this line
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow()
    {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        mRelativeLayoutAchievement1.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener); //Also get NPE on this line
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me the proper way to get a hold of my subviews, in this case mRelativeLayoutAchievement1?

Here's an XML snippet:

```
<com.beachbody.p90x.achievements.ViewAchievements xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_very_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- kv Row 1 -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_achievement1"
            style="@style/linearLayout_achievement"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_sm"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_achievement1"
                style="@style/text_small_bold_gray"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:text="1/20" />
        </RelativeLayout>
...
```

And here's how I'm creating the view from my Activity:

```
public class ActivityAchievements extends ActivitySlidingMenu
{
    private ViewAchievements mViewAchievements;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mViewAchievements = (ViewAchievements) View.inflate(this, R.layout.view_achievements, null);
        setContentView(mViewAchievements);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the child views during the view's constructor. Since they are child views, they haven't been inflated yet. Can you move this code out of the constructor, possibly into View.onAttachedToWindow()?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onAttachedToWindow()

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried putting the setOnClickListener() in the onAttachedToWindow(), but I still get the NPE. Any other suggestions? I added my Activity code above.